# Change mode of MooTools Slider to vertical

Tags: slider, mootools

I tried to change the mode to vertical on the slider as it's an option on the .js, but it just doesn't work, please this is driving me crazy.

here's the slider: http://developer.expressionz.in/downloads/mootools_double_pinned_slider_with_clipped_gutter_image_v2.2/slider_using_mootols_1.2.html

```
/*mode - either 'horizontal' or 'vertical'. defaults to horizontal.*/

mode: 'vertical',
```

Comment: I've downloaded slider sources from your link, and added `mode: 'vertical`. It works, but you'll need to update your CSS to make it work correctly.

Comment: can you tell me which lines to change please?

Comment: You'll need to change many lines in CSS, for example lines, which are responsible for `background`, `height` etc. Just try to modify their example with `mode: 'vertical'` for all sliders and then update CSS line by line.